# Two different loss functions with different labels in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, loss-function

I am training a network with two paths, each consisting of several conv layers. One path belongs to video input, and the other path belongs to audio input. At some point, I mix the features and then apply some other conv layers and fully connected layers toward the output of the network.

I want to define two separate loss functions: `loss1` just before mixing the audio and video features, and `loss2` at the output. The problem is that the labels are different for each optimization function. 
I have a two class label for the mix layer that indicate whether the video and audio are match, and another two class label at the end of network that indicate certain action in the video.

Any suggestions on how I should define my two loss functions, optimizers and train the network in tensorflow? Note that although the labels and loss functions are different, the majority of the network is the same.

Thanks,

Comment: [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)